# someone has access to my acer chromebook and my phone also

Tags: attacks

I lived with another person while I was attending school online. I was using his WiFi for phone and computer. When I left, all my passwords were changed, my settings, everything that could possibly be changed has been. My photos deleted, eventually my Chromebook has been totally disabled, will not even turn on.

I've received an email from Google saying my email and password was used to log in from Moscow, but was stopped. Is there any way to prove this was done? What can I do to stop it?

Comment: Have you try factory reset your chromebook and phone ?

Comment: "prove this was done"? Prove *what* was done?

Comment: It is not clear what you are really asking here.

Answer (score -2):

When you say Chromebook that means you are referring to same Google account as your Gmail. You have probably been phished and that provided access to your Google account, from there to your Chromebook, from there to your browser (or this can be skipped and the attacker can use your credentials in any Chrome browser to sync your browser data including passwords), from there your password and might have deleted your photos.

Also did you check the SSL certificate CA of Gmail from your Wifi? Just in-case it is intercepted.

If the router default password is not changed and the firewall is open (assuming old routers) it is easy to get attacked.

Also check if your router IP is recorded in Shodan search.

Finally, you can barely know what had happened but it is not easy to prove who did it.

Comment: Much of your advice is not very helpful. The user is obviously not technologically savvy, so "check the SSL certificate CA of Gmail" needs a lot of explanation, as does "check if your router IP is recorded in Shodan". The user has left the network, so checking is not going to be helpful nor is checking the router's IP. You also contradict yourself. If there was a man-in-the-middle, then the user was not phished. None of this answer helps the OP with what to do *now*, they are all steps to investigate the possible ways the initial problem occurred.